# Using ObservableCollection<T> as a FIFO stack

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have built a heart rate monitoring device, from which I intend to send data to my mobile application.

In my mobile application, I want to show a cardiogram as a dynamic curve which updates corresponding to the real-time data that the device sends to it.

Currently, I'm though concerned with preparing the data that I intend to append to my graph, and for that sake, I've written a code that reads the data from the peripheral and adds it to an observable collection:

```
MyDevice.Characteristic.ValueUpdated += (sender, e) =>
{
       HrData = new ObservableCollection<string>();            
       HrData.Add(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Characteristic.Value));        
};
```

Now, since the device is reading a lot of data in a very small timespan, I intend to only show 20 data points in the graph, meaning that the list should be updated according to the FIFO principle.

I know, that I could just make a loop and move every entity in my collection and thus achieve the principle. I do however feel that it would be a "pathcy" way of doing this.

- Do there exist any convenient way to do this? i.e. an observable stack class.

Comment: Use a [queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're fundamentally looking for is a queue.  A queue is a First In, First Out mechanism (as opposed to a Stack, which is First In, Last Out mechanism.)

Comment: And then implement it in an interface?

Comment: ... why do you need to implement it?  Why can't you just use it?  Whatever objects you want to store in the FIFO queue, you just use Queue<TypeOfObjectBeingStored>  It's the same thing as, say, List<T> - you don't generally want to implement your own List - you just use List<ObjectType>

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe you will have to implement Queue<T> after all.  Might be worth figuring out, though, if you could have the individual objects be observable instead of the overarching collection though.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection` does not support this scenario. What you can do:

- create your own implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged`
- or: subclass `ObservableCollection`, suspend notifications while you update the contents and then raise a `Reset` event
- or: re-create the collection each time
- or: create two separate collections, and switch between them: you expose A while updating B, then you expose B while updating A

Answer (score 0):

```
class ObservableQueue<T> : Queue<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public ObservableQueue()
    {
    }

    public ObservableQueue(int capacity) : base(capacity)
    {
    }

    public ObservableQueue(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public new void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        if(this.CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public new void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        base.Enqueue(item);
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add));
    }

    public new T Dequeue()
    {
        T item = base.Dequeue();
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove));
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: From this I get the error: "Constructor only supports reset operation" o.0